# Dynamically create file folder based on line 1 in csv

Tags: python-3.x

This script downloads images, renames them based on `line[0]` adds a number to the end of the file name and saves them to a file folder. My goal here is to create the file folder name based on `line[0]` of my csv file, I'm new to python and need to download/sort 15000+ images. Any help would be appreciated! Using python 3.8.6

Note: 1 model may contain many images so the idea is to create the folder, place images for that model inside, move on to the next model, etc.

Csv file content

```
    RHV3-484-L,https://www.fisherpaykel.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-fpa-master-catalog/default/dw0c85e188/product-mugs/cooking/ranges/mug/retail/RHV3-484-N-RHV3-484-L-external-mug-rs-84.png
RHV3-484-L,https://www.fisherpaykel.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-fpa-master-catalog/default/dwcbd711e5/inspire/caitlin-wilson-portland-dk-339-rs-84.png
RHV3-484-L,https://www.fisherpaykel.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-fpa-master-catalog/default/dw3702e52a/inspire/caitlin-wilson-portland-dk-385-rs-84.jpg
RHV3-484-L,https://www.fisherpaykel.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-fpa-master-catalog/default/dw0c85e188/product-mugs/cooking/ranges/mug/retail/RHV3-484-N-RHV3-484-L-external-mug-rs-84.png
RHV3-484-L,https://www.fisherpaykel.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-fpa-master-catalog/default/dwf99a5a9d/inspire/david-berridge-project-brooklyn-mw-6457-rs-84.jpg
```

Python script

```
import sys
import urllib
import urllib.request
from csv import reader
import os.path
import os

csv_filename = "images"

with open(csv_filename+".csv".format(csv_filename), 'r') as csv_file:
    n = 1
    for line in reader(csv_file):
        if not os.path.exists("ImageID"):
            os.makedirs("ImageID")
            print("Image skipped for {0}".format(line[0]))
        else:
            if line[1] != '' and line[0] != "ImageID":
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(line[1], "ImageID/" + line[0] + "-" + str(n) + ".jpg")
                n += 1
                print("Image saved for {0}".format(line[0]))
            else:
                print("No result for {0}".format(line[0]))
```

Comment: all of the lines in your CSV appear to be the same?  Also, you appear to be trying to make the same folder every time in the loop with name "ImageID".  Can you clarify the csv and the intent a bit?

Comment: @AirSquid please see edits. I hope this provides some clarity. Thanks.

Comment: So you want folders from the first element... so folders like "RHV3-484-L" (and presumably others) or are there multiple options for line[0] and you want to put the file in the correct folder?  Also...  Your question isn't specific about what exactly you are having trouble with.  Good questions usually say what the desired outcome is and any errors along the way.....  hint hint.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work as desired....

Couple comments in middle.  Notably, you need to respect the .jpg or .png file.  If you have file extensions that are longer (4 chars) you may need to split out the file name and then split by "."

Good Luck!

```
import sys
import urllib
import urllib.request
from csv import reader
import os.path
import os

csv_filename = "images.csv"

with open(csv_filename, 'r') as csv_file:
    n = 1  # starting point
    for line in reader(csv_file):
        tgt_folder = line[0] 
        if not os.path.exists(tgt_folder):
            os.makedirs(tgt_folder)
            n = 1  # restart n if you find a NEW folder
        # there should be no "else" clause here.  Just test the folder name above, but don't waste a file
        if line[1] != '' and line[0] != "ImageID":  # not clear what this is for... ??
            filename = ''.join([line[0], '-', str(n), line[1][-4:]])
            destination = os.path.join(tgt_folder, filename)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(line[1], destination)
            n += 1
            print("Image saved for {0}".format(line[1]))
        else:
            print("No result for {0}".format(line[1]))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I appreciate the help!